# Spread operator used in conjuction with a function in ES6 , inside Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I was just going through habitica code (a vue.js app) and came across the below spread operator usage like so [HERE](https://github.com/HabitRPG/habitica/blob/develop/website/client/components/tasks/task.vue#L576). Inside computed you have the following:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState({
    user: 'user.data',
    castingSpell: 'spellOptions.castingSpell',
    isRunningYesterdailies: 'isRunningYesterdailies',
  }),
}
```

Now i've never seem the spread operator used in conjuction with a function , not sure whats happning here, the `mapState` happnens to be a function present in another file, that looks like so:

```
export function mapState (states) {
  const res = {};

  normalizeMap(states).forEach(({ key, val }) => {
    res[key] = function mappedState () {
      return typeof val === 'function' ?
        val.call(this, this.$store.state, this.$store.getters) :
        get(this.$store.state, val);
    };
  });

  return res;
}
```

I understand the spread operator when used with an `Array` or an `Object`, but what exactly is happening here with a function ?

Comment: The function *returns* an object, that's what the spread operator is being used with.

Comment: function is returning an object, which is eventually getting spreaded to place value on your `computed` object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is returning an `Object` which is being getting spread-ed,

You can understand with a simple example

- Here `func` is a function which creates an object based on value passed to it
- inside `me` object i have one property called `info` which i want to set as an object, so i simply call `func` with `name and age` and spread

```js
let func = (name,age)=> ({name,age})

let me = {
  info: {...func('code maniac', 24)}
}

console.log(me)
```

Comment: thanks , but is't the `computed` property inside vue.js suppose to hold only functions ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik the values of the object *are* functions.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik not actually as it an object you assign any valid value, eventually what this function is doing is assigning `key/value`  but based on some condition or argument